# Can I see what is eliminated by the Visual C++ /OPT:REF linker option?

Tags: visual-c++, linker

The `/OPT:REF` option causes the Visual C++ linker to

> Exclude functions and/or data that are never referenced

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx))

This seems like it would be a good way to identify obsolete code in a legacy codebase. Is there any way to get the linker to output what is eliminated?

Answer (score 8):

In  [/OPT (Optimizations)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx), the Remarks section states:

> You can use the [/VERBOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx) option to see the functions removed by /OPT:REF and the functions that are folded by /OPT:ICF.

I have not tried using it for your purpose yet.

Also, you may want to refer to [SO Question 641826](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641826/what-is-unwind-in-a-linker-map-file) to eliminate compiler-generated symbols if you take the route given by @JamesMcNellis [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509041/can-i-see-what-is-eliminated-by-the-visual-c-optref-linker-option/1551499#1551499).

Answer (score 3):

This isn't ideal, but...

You can do two builds, one with `/OPT:REF` and one without, then run `dumpbin /symbols` on the resulting binaries, parse out the symbols, and diff the results.  The trick will be weeding out the library symbols so you are only left with your symbols.  Since you'll end up with a list of mangled names, it's not going to be pretty.

I don't know of a way to get the linker to just tell you what it's removing.